# GREP: Extracting all characters from inside double quote

Tags: regex, shell, unix, grep

What I did:

**grep -E -o -e "[^"]+"**

It can extract, for example: "Poland" and "New York" but can't extract "Marcos Juárez" due to the existence of 'á'...it cuts the output to "Marcos Ju" and "rez"

How can I prevent this?

Comment: I cannot reproduce your problem, with your regex, the expected output was given. could it be the locale problem in your terminal?

Comment: If I use grep -c it gives me three matches, which is right. However, I place the output in a file and the '| wc -l' in this case becomes 4 and not 3.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is a regex problem per say. It could be a Unicode or wide-char issue.
Your regex should be `"[^"]+"` thats a NOT double quote.

I don't know unix command line, but what is delimiting the `"[^']+"` parameter,
is it done by just spaces ?

Try `".*?"`, it should match. If not its a unicode problem.

Comment: I am already using "[^"]+" (edited my question). And your regex returned everything.

Comment: @Atieh - If `".*?"` returns everything, then the regex is `.*?` not `".*?"`, meaning the double quotes are being stripped by the command line processor. I don't know Unix, but I know regex.

Comment: ".*?" syntax is right, but it return everything. I think I will right a script that removes first and last characters ("...") for each word and that would solve it. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
grep -Po  '(?<=\")(.*?)(?=\")'
```

for me it output all the three correctly.

Comment: Error: Conflicting matchers specified

Comment: Please post the input file. I ran it on your examples and it worked fine on two Linux machines.

Comment: For the cities without the " ", I did:
awk -F , '{print $4}' cities.txt | grep -E -o "[^"]+"

If I add -c to grep, it returns matches equal to num of lines in text file, however if I pipe it to 'wc -l' it gives me less number of lines.

Comment: @Atieh unlike the examples above, cities.txt has many elements (on each line) that are surrounded by quotes. I suspect that it'll be much easier to write a small parser than to grep it using regex.

Comment: I need the city names only. I obtained them using awk, what I want is names without "" and my problem is with chars like 'á'